# 404 page not found error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have created a route in routes.php

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'quotation'], function () {
        Route::get('data', 'QuotationController@data');
        Route::post('send_quotation', 'QuotationController@sendQuotation');
        Route::get('{quotation}/show', 'QuotationController@show');
        Route::get('{quotation}/edit', 'QuotationController@edit');
        Route::get('{quotation}/delete', 'QuotationController@delete');
        Route::get('{quotation}/ajax_create_pdf', 'QuotationController@ajaxCreatePdf');
        Route::get('{quotation}/print_quot', 'QuotationController@printQuot');
        Route::get('{quotation}/make_invoice', 'QuotationController@makeInvoice');
       Route::get('{quotation}/approve', 'QuotationController@approve');
        Route::get('{quotation}/confirm_sales_order', 'QuotationController@confirmSalesOrder');
        Route::put('{quotation}', 'QuotationController@update');
        Route::delete('{quotation}', 'QuotationController@destroy');
        Route::get('ajax_qtemplates_products/{qtemplate}', 'QuotationController@ajaxQtemplatesProducts');
        Route::get('ajax_sales_team_list', 'QuotationController@ajaxSalesTeamList');

        Route::get('draft_quotations_list/data', 'QuotationController@draftQuotations');
        Route::get('draft_quotations', 'QuotationController@draftIndex');
    });
    Route::resource('quotation', 'QuotationController');
```

But when I am running the url :

`quotation/34/edit`

then it is showing error :

`Page not Found`

Please help me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you try commenting your resource route line and run the url

Comment: Do you definitely have a `quotation` with the id of 34? Can you show the method you have for `QuotationController@edit`?

Comment: Are you updating it via form or just showing edit form ? Try using both GET and POST for edit one for displaying form and one for submitting it to database.

Answer (score 0):

move your last line to first actually you are overriding Laravel routes by mistake:

```
Route::resource('quotation', 'QuotationController');
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'quotations'], function () { // Here I changed 
        Route::get('data', 'QuotationController@data');
        Route::post('send_quotation', 'QuotationController@sendQuotation');
        Route::get('{quotation}/show', 'QuotationController@show');
        Route::get('{quotation}/edit', 'QuotationController@edit');
        Route::get('{quotation}/delete', 'QuotationController@delete');
        Route::get('{quotation}/ajax_create_pdf', 'QuotationController@ajaxCreatePdf');
        Route::get('{quotation}/print_quot', 'QuotationController@printQuot');
        Route::get('{quotation}/make_invoice', 'QuotationController@makeInvoice');
       Route::get('{quotation}/approve', 'QuotationController@approve');
        Route::get('{quotation}/confirm_sales_order', 'QuotationController@confirmSalesOrder');
        Route::put('{quotation}', 'QuotationController@update');
        Route::delete('{quotation}', 'QuotationController@destroy');
        Route::get('ajax_qtemplates_products/{qtemplate}', 'QuotationController@ajaxQtemplatesProducts');
        Route::get('ajax_sales_team_list', 'QuotationController@ajaxSalesTeamList');

        Route::get('draft_quotations_list/data', 'QuotationController@draftQuotations');
        Route::get('draft_quotations', 'QuotationController@draftIndex');
    });
```

Actually **resource** method of Laravel automatic create default urls. Check Laravel [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) for more info. 
Good Luck!!

Comment: just put only one line into your routes.php file:
Route::resource('quotation', 'QuotationController');

Answer (score 0):

it breaks because you have defined routes and after added: `Route::resource('quotation', 'QuotationController');`

I advise to Keep `Route::resource`! Have a close look on [Laravel Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
Route::get('{quotation}/{id}/edit', 'QuotationController@edit');
```

Also, in the controller pass the parameter `($id)` if you have not passed it already.

Comment: Will have the same result, because he have a `Route::resource('quotation', 'QuotationController');` after.

Also you wrapped `{quotation}` so it means 2 values in controller `$quotation, $id`